# Should Postman be returning a 400 error when I do a get on Google.com

Tags: http, postman, httprequest

Currently when I do a Get request on google.com, I get a 400 error return code

[image: postman 400 error code]

Is this expected behavior?  I was expecting an HTML response.

If a 400 error is expected, why?  Shouldn't we be returned with some HTML just like when we do a GET request in browser?

If a 400 error is not expected,  why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a miss-configured proxy (file->settings->proxy).

Once configured properly, this was the result:

[image: google request in postman]